# In Java, what if you're using List because you coded to an interface but later, because you have a LinkedList, you need to use getFirst()?

Tags: java, list, interface

I get the advantages of coding to an interface, but what do you do if you later find that you need a method that's only available in the concrete implementation. Do you then go back and change the variable type from the interface to the implementation?

Comment: `get(0)` works for all List types and with the same efficiency of constant time complexity. Why not use that instead of `getFirst()`?

Comment: if "*you need a method that's only available in the concrete implementation*" then you are not "*coding to an interface*" (or, in that specific case, coding to the wrong interface, maybe it should be a `Queue` or `Deque` \[in coming version [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)]

Comment: If the function you need can be implemented via the interface and is trivial like here, just use `get(0)`. If it's non-trivial, then it should probably have been a default method on the interface (or static utility) and not an instance method on one concrete type. If it can't reasonably be implemented through the interface, then you're coding against the wrong interface.

Comment: getFirst is defined by the Deque interface

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Java 8+, I recommend you to use the stream API for getting the first element of a `List`.

```java
List x;
x.stream().findFirst().orElse();
```

You can use `get(0)` too, but IMO this is not good because it can throw a `NullPointerException` if the list is null or another `Exception`, if the list is empty.

Comment: Sorry, it is called "findFirst()". What about get(0) in empty list? Kind greetings....